# Wrong ExtJS5 Grid render

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Learning ExtJS5 I have a problem with grid. I have such panel description:

```
{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Texts',
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        reference: 'textGrid',
                        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields: ['active', 'textValue'],
                            data: {
                                items: [
                                    {active: true, textValue: 'test'},
                                    {active: false, textValue: 'no test'}
                                ]
                            },
                            proxy: {
                                type: 'memory',
                                reader: {
                                    type: 'json',
                                    rootProperty: 'items'
                                }
                            }
                        }),
                        columns: [
                            { xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                                text: 'Enable', dataIndex: 'active', width: 100,
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                    cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor'
                                }
                            },
                            { text: 'Value', dataIndex: 'textValue', flex: 1,
                                editor: {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                }
                            }

                        ],
                        plugins: {
                            ptype: 'rowediting',
                            clicksToEdit: 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Images',
                        xtype: 'gridpanel'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

But it's rendered wrong. I don't see a checkbox and area for text column is too small. There're no any errors in firebug console.

[image: Grid]

What's wrong with code?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, it works as it is when copied into a Sencha [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7td). Apparently you're missing some CSS for the grid though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it looks like this sometimes happens when there are requires missing in your classes.

Look into the console for warnings like these:

```
[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.layout.container.Border'; consider adding  Ext.require('Ext.layout.container.Border') above Ext.onReady
```

And add the missing classes to the requires array of the class that uses them like this:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.container.Border',
        'Ext.tab.Panel'
    ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles are missing.

If you created the proyect with Sencha Command (you are loading proyect with microloader bootstrap, see your index.html), then you must be sure you have defined all requires of the components that you used on your app and launch this command from the root directory:

```
sencha app build
```

This command compile the css that will be use on your app (among other things). You can try too:

```
sencha app refresh
```

And a latest two command if the latest don't work (use both):

```
sencha app clean
sencha app build
```

Hope it work